# What's the meaning of delegates here?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

> However, the latest versions of ImageMagick doesn’t properly filter the file names that get passed to the internal delegates that handle external protocols (like HTTPS).

I search the word 'delegate' in [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delegate?q=delegates)，and found much meaning. I think the explaination 'to give a particular job, duty, right, etc. to someone else so that they do it for you:' may be appropriate. But I don't know what be delegated. I guess that maybe the internal or file names?

Source: [imagemagick-remote-command-execution-vulnerability](https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/05/imagemagick-remote-command-execution-vulnerability.html)

Comment: The word *delegates* is a plural **noun** in your sentence. It is part of the noun phrase *the internal delegates*, which is being modified by the relative clause *that handle external protocols...*

Comment: This sounds like a programming question, try asking this question on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(computing)) gives the sense you're asking about, but asking on another site would be more appropriate.

Comment: This question belongs on another site, possibly in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: D_D, the close-vote system slavishly repeats your reason for the close-vote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a programming questions and belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning that you found is appropriate. It's pretty common in computer science to make use of [deverbal nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun). Essentially, what they're saying is that the part of the program to which the responsibility for handling file names is delegated has a vulnerability. Hence the use of "delegates". Having read the blog post, I would assume they're using "delegates" both to avoid having to go into too much detail about ImageMagick's architecture, and to cover a wide variety of potential attack vectors. The responsibility for handling file names is delegated to various parts of the program based on protocol, one assumes. They are calling all of those parts "delegates", collectively.